# (JNI) is object returned by java code need DeleteLocalRef?

Tags: java-native-interface

i have searched all over the world knowing that, we should DeleteLocalRef if it's created in JNI code
then, should i also delete it if the object is newed and returned by Java code? such as:

```
// in java code
public SomeObject funcInJavaCode() {
    return new SomeObject();
}
// in jni code
funcInJNI {
    jobject obj = env->CallObjectMethod(...);
    ...
    // do i have to delete the obj here???
    env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);
}
```

thanks

Comment: *The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification* by Sheng Liang (JNI's designer) is a key reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Local references are garbage collected when the native function returns to Java (when Java calls native) or when the calling thread is detached from the JVM (in native calls Java). You need explicit `DeleteLocalRef` only when you have a long lived native function (e.g., a main loop) or create a large number of transient objects in a loop.

Comment: so it's not wrong to delete it, then is it a good opinion that ALWAYS delete it instead of GC? can it cause performance problem?

Comment: Local references are only GC'd in the sense that they are "cleaned up".  They are normally cleaned up directly by popping them off the stack, not by processing them through the garbage collector analysis.

Comment: My app crashed `JNI error : Local reference table overflow 512 entries` when calling my java method many times. Then i added `DeleteLocalRef` and the problem was solved.

Comment: how about void native function? Java calls void native function and back to java thread again should I deleteLocalRef?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can NOT delete the local ref to a returned object since that call will free up the reference to the object. For example

```
    jbitmap = invokeObjectJavaMethod("MFImageToNative", "([B)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;", byte_array);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(jbitmap);

    return jbitmap;
```

will crash, I believe that it the consumer of the method's responsibility to deal with freeing up the reference. I some kind soul could provide clarification on how to do this, I would be most grateful.