# How to pass a ArrayList<Point> for a jni C++ function?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am doing a project in Java with Android jni C++. I have a function in C++ with the following parameters:

**C++ function:**
`void rectify (vector <Point2f> & corners, Mat & img) {...}`

In **JAVA**, call would be:

```
Mat image = Highgui.imread("img.png");
List <MatOfPoint> cornners =  new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();;
Point b = new Point (real_x2, real_y2);
MatOfPoint ma = new MatOfPoint (b);
cornners.add(ma);
rectfy(image.getNativeObjAddr(), cornners)
```

`public native void rectfy(long mat, "??" matofpoint);`

With that, I wonder how will the function C++ jni:

`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ImageProcessingActivity_rectfy (JNIEnv * jobject, ?? cornners, inputMatAddress jlong)`

Comment: Have you tried creating a Java native method with the interface you want on the Java side, and using `javah` to create the C side header?

Comment: I'm doing in **Eclipse** with **NDK**. I have a .java which has a statement of a native method, referencing a .cpp it is loaded with `System.loadLibrary ("rectifylib")`, _"rectifylib"_ points to _jni-parts.cpp_ which is inside the folder and **jni** It has the method `JNICALL Java_ImageProcessingActivity_rectfy (...)_.`

Comment: You wonder how will the function *what*? What's the question? Are you looking for the keyword `void`?

Comment: What I wonder is how to pass an `ArrayList <MatOfPoint2f> (vector <Point2f>)` java for a code in C ++ jni. What would be the type of the parameter that the function in C ++ would receive?

Comment: To my understanding, In JNI, all classes (non-primitives) are passed as `jobject`. In a similar manner, when you want to pass back Java classes from C++, you return a `jobject` which has been instantiated as, for example, an `ArrayList`. I think you can find several JNI examples/tutorials that explains this better than I do.

Comment: can't you just pass a `MatOfPoint` with multiple rows, one per `Point`, passing it as a regular `Mat` through native address?

Comment: In **JAVA**, I have a `ArrayList <Points> corners` with 4 points (a, b, c, and d) that represent the corners of a quadrilateral image. Already in the code in **C ++**, I have to represent these points as a `vector <Point2f> corners`, that's the problem. How to make this transformation `ArrayList <Points> corners` to `vector <Point2f> corners`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that what you want to do is to pass a bunch of points from Java to C++, then I think this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
#include <vector>
#include <jni.h>

class Point2f {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Point2f(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ImageProcessingActivity_transferPointsToNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject self, jobject input) {
    jclass alCls = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
    jclass ptCls = env->FindClass("java/awt/Point");

    if (alCls == nullptr || ptCls == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    jmethodID alGetId  = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jmethodID alSizeId = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "size", "()I");
    jmethodID ptGetXId = env->GetMethodID(ptCls, "getX", "()D");
    jmethodID ptGetYId = env->GetMethodID(ptCls, "getY", "()D");

    if (alGetId == nullptr || alSizeId == nullptr || ptGetXId == nullptr || ptGetYId == nullptr) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(ptCls);
        return;
    }

    int pointCount = static_cast<int>(env->CallIntMethod(input, alSizeId));

    if (pointCount < 1) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(ptCls);
        return;
    }

    std::vector<Point2f> points;
    points.reserve(pointCount);
    double x, y;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i) {
        jobject point = env->CallObjectMethod(input, alGetId, i);
        x = static_cast<double>(env->CallDoubleMethod(point, ptGetXId));
        y = static_cast<double>(env->CallDoubleMethod(point, ptGetYId));
        env->DeleteLocalRef(point);

        points.push_back(Point2f(x, y));
    }

    env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(ptCls);
}
```

With a corresponding method declaration in Java:

```
private native void transferPointsToNative(ArrayList<Point> input);
```

Comment: For posterity / the record, you'll want to `env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls` and `ptCls)` before returning from `Java_com_example_ImageProcessingActivity_transferPointsToNative`, and `env->DeleteLocalRef(point)` within the loop to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: These local references e.g. alCls are just local variable that are placed on the stack, just like all local variable in c/c++. So why do you need to delete them? They are automatically deleted when the native-function returns? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567851/jni-is-object-returned-by-java-code-need-deletelocalref